# org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.spilt() weird behavior

Tags: java, split

```
    String sperator = "__"; // or "_____"
    String[] a = StringUtils.split("A__B_C__D", sperator);
    for (String string :(a) ){
        System.out.println(string);
    }
```

No matter how many "_" sperator has, the output is always

```
A
B
C
D
```

However the java.lang.String.spilt could get expected result.
Is that an intention or expection？

Comment: I believe that the separator string is just used as a collection of individual characters, each of which can be a separator. So using `sperator="___"` instead of `"_"` would make no difference.

Comment: What is your expected result? `A` `B_C` `D`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is intended as said by the [javadoc](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.4/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

> Adjacent separators are treated as one separator.

Comment: can you post the URL  from this statement ?

Comment: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html

Comment: @AlvaroJoao,always look to the API for answers and if you can't find what you're looking for, then refer to the source code.  [API](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.4/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), [source code](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=commons-lang.git;a=blob;f=src/main/java/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.java)

Answer (score 1):

As I checked the API doc, 
It's said:

```
    // Splitting
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
/**
 * <p>Splits the provided text into an array, using whitespace as the
 * separator.
 * Whitespace is defined by {@link Character#isWhitespace(char)}.</p>
 *
 * <p>The separator is not included in the returned String array.
 * Adjacent separators are treated as one separator.
 * For more control over the split use the StrTokenizer class.</p>
 *
 * <p>A {@code null} input String returns {@code null}.</p>
 *
 * <pre>
 * StringUtils.split(null)       = null
 * StringUtils.split("")         = []
 * StringUtils.split("abc def")  = ["abc", "def"]
 * StringUtils.split("abc  def") = ["abc", "def"]
 * StringUtils.split(" abc ")    = ["abc"]
 * </pre>
 *
 * @param str  the String to parse, may be null
 * @return an array of parsed Strings, {@code null} if null String input
 */
public static String[] split(final String str) {
    return split(str, null, -1);
}
```

As you see, ***"Adjacent separators are treated as one separator."***
And the demo code also tell the truth:

```
  StringUtils.split("abc def")  = ["abc", "def"]
  StringUtils.split("abc  def") = ["abc", "def"]
```

For more details:https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/index.html

And for java.lang.String.split, the first param is a "regex expression", It's fully matched.
For more details the api doc:

```
public String[] split(String regex)
```

Splits this string around matches of the given regular expression.
This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with the given expression and a limit argument of zero. Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.

The string "boo:and:foo", for example, yields the following results with these expressions:

Regex   Result
:   { "boo", "and", "foo" }
o   { "b", "", ":and:f" }

The api doc is :http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/

And at last,if you are not sure how it is implemented inner, the source code will tell you the truth and help you remember it more clear.